# Configuring Subversion Version Control In Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, dreamweaver

We're setting up Subversion version control in Dreamweaver CS4 and we'd like to transmit our files over SSL.  We have it working without SSL.  But, when we select HTTPS as the protocol, it's unable to connect. https://thedevserver.edu, DW fails to connect.
Has anyone gotten this to work?  Is there something on the Apache or Subversion sides that we're missing?

We have an SVN configuration include file with the following contents:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module    modules/mod_dav_svn.so
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /folder/folder1/SVN_REPOS_folder
    SVNListParentPath on
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName webdav
    AuthDigestDomain /repos
    AuthUserFile /some/where/on/the/server
    AuthDigestProvider file
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I've **Included** this file in the virtual host file.  But, still, DW can't connect using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to http repo, but can't to https: this is obviously **Apache** part - it must support secure connection for used for repository virtualhost or server.

Subversion (mod_dav_svn) in this case work over base httpd-engine